# $('#list').jqgrid is not a function

Tags: jqgrid

I'm trying to use jqgrid and I got this error: *$('#list').jqgrid is not a function*

My js files are loaded from another url than the one my page is displayed.

Here is my head's js includes:

```
<script src="http://js.abc.com/js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://js.abc.com/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://js.abc.com/js/jqgrid/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://js.abc.com/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://js.abc.com/js/jquery.layout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

my js code to load the grid:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
      $('#list').jqgrid({});
   });
</script>
```

When I look at the page source code and click on the js links, the js code is there.

Did I miss something?

Comment: If you're using FF or Chrome, look in the console and see what errors you're getting. You might be missing some dependency.

Comment: ...or some other script might be dying.

Comment: That's the only error I have in the console:   $("#list").jqgrid is not a function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$('#list').jqgrid({});` is really wrong. You should use

```
$('#list').jqGrid({});
```

(with capital 'G') instead.